# Error when catching objects and lives count wont decrease?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, counter, collision

I'm currently making a catching game. So the user have to catch the right letter to get a score and go to the next question.
The letters are movieclips and I made the falling animation with motion tween.
I converted the avatar to a movieclip too.
When the avatar hits the right letter, the user will get 100 points and when the avatar hits the wrong letter, there will be a pop up button that says "try again" and it will lost its lives by 1.
Here's my code:

```
stop();
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveavatar);
avatarmove.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision);

trybutton.visible = false;
var myscore = 0; 
var mylives = 5;
score.text = myscore+"";
lives.text = mylives+"";

//Move avatar function
function moveavatar (event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
  avatarmove.x = Math.max(0,Math.min(stage.stageWidth-avatarmove.width,avatarmove.x - int(event.keyCode==37) * 10 + int(event.keyCode==39) * 10));
}

//Collision between the avatar and the letters
function handleCollision(e:Event):void
{
    if(avatarmove.hitTestObject(a_alphabet))
       {
    myscore+=100;
    a_alphabet.visible = false;
    gotoAndStop(2);
       }
  else if(avatarmove.hitTestObject(o_alphabet))
       {
    mylives-=1;
    o_alphabet.visible = false;
    trybutton.visible = true;
       }
}

//try again button
trybutton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, ayo1);
function ayo1(event:MouseEvent):void{
  o_alphabet.visible = true;
  trybutton.visible = false;
}
```

I keep getting this error when the avatar hits the letter:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
at gamecompletethewords_fla::MainTimeline/handleCollision()
```

And this error on the next frame:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at gamecompletethewords_fla::MainTimeline/handleCollision2()
```

And the the lives won't decrease when the avatar hits the wrong letter, but when I move to the next frame it will decrease by -27. It's just really weird.
Can someone help me with these problems? I'm totally new to this and I have no idea how to fix it :(

Comment: The error is because either `o_alphabet` or `a_alphabet` is null or undefined when your `handleCollision` function is run.   Without knowing more about how `a/o_alphabet` are created, it's hard to tell you why.  MOST LIKELY, you have them on a certain frame, and then you change frames and they are gone, or don't have instance names anymore.  Remember too, that when you add an ENTER_FRAME handler, it stays around until explicitly removed (changing frames doesn't make it go away)

Comment: I created the a/o_alphabet as moving movieclips, I created motion tweens inside the movieclips so they will fall down from the top of the screen, I placed them outside the stage height and they fall down to the bottom of the screen. I'm really new to this so I don't know if I do it the right way or not